# help needed with finding the total automorphisms for graph $H$ of a cube

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

Paragraph copied from Bona.

"Let $f \in  Aut(H)$ and let A be a vertex of the cube. Then we have 8 choices for $f(A)$. Once $f(A)$ is chosen, the neighbors of $A$ in $H$ must be mapped into the neighbors of $f(A)$ by $f$. Since $A$ has three neighbors, this is possible in $3!$ ways. Once the images of the neighbors are chosen, there are no more choices to make (why?)"

I played around by drawing pictures and it is clear that the other vertices are fixed once $f(A)$ and neighbors of $f(A)$ are chosen. But why? How does one prove that the others will be fixed and will not contribute to the total automorphisms?

Thanks

Comment: Try thinking about the unique vertex $B$ satisfying $N(B) \cap (A \cup f(A)) = \emptyset$ (i.e. $B$ is the "opposite corner" vertex from the perspective of $A$). Once we have this, all three neighbors of each of the three remaining "unaccounted for" vertices are determined exactly. Why is this enough to draw the desired conclusion?